# Angular 2 IIS URL updating before route parameters

Tags: angular, url, iis, routes

I am using Angular 4 on an IIS server and need to change the URL on page load of the app.

Our code currently sits in a folder location like 
../app/anotherfolder/dist/

..and the site URL returns..

http://localhost:8888/app/anotherfolder/dist/angular2route/....

I need to remove the “/app/anotherfolder/dist” from the URL so its just..

http://localhost:8888/angular2route/...

The folder location cannot be changed (one of my many constraints I’m afraid) otherwise there wouldn’t be an issue as I could just add this to the root of the IIS site itself.

I have the site working using IIS rewrite rules to serve the content.

I am using the Path Location Strategy (as I can’t use HashLocation due to yet more constraints) but I can’t figure out (having looked all over the Interwebs) how to amend the URL BEFORE the routing parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have **base** tag in html at header?

You use **routelink** for routing? How you use **link**?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have by baseHref set to 'app/anotherfolder/dist' (i.e., the relative path of the app). I am using an array of routes built from @angular/router as a common app-routing module. The site is called externally initially from an MVC web site so Im trying to set the URL structure before any Angular routing occurs.

Comment: You need make relative path from IIS settings to root of angular application.